# The first time I was seen was for Christmas - Who Am I?

Tags: riddle

*First question here, let me know if anything needs improvement*

> The first time I was seen was for Christmas
>
> My First name is the same as my mothers surname
>
> My job gives me and you power
>
> Although I am the weakest I dance better than most

Who am I?

*It is a character in a TV series/Movie*

Comment: Good one! I think you could have saved the last line of your question as a hint for later, but it is just my opinion :).

Comment: @ IAmInPLS So did I but since it was my first riddle I decided to play it safe, I also had other hints that I was going to use, saddly I was unable to though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you:

> Mr. Burns? I'm surprised your name didn't give it away to more people.

*The first time I was seen was for Christmas*

> His first episode was a Christmas Episode on Dec 17, 1989. "Simpsons Roasting on an Open Fire"

*My First name is the same as my mothers surname*

> Mr. Burns' first name is Charles, also his mother's maiden name, Daphne Charles

*My job gives me and you power*

> He owns the Springfield Power Plant

*Although I am the weakest I dance better than most*

> A very old and frail character but quite the dancer

Comment: Excellent~ You are correct, I was hoping for some more answers and replying as such, for hints, but seems there was no need

Comment: Also with regards to my name, it wasnt intentional for this riddle however it set it up quite nicely